# PHP concatenar string + variável com obj->metodo

Tags: php

Quero chamar um método automaticamente se determinada situação ocorrer para isso estou tentando montar o nome desse método.

Os métodos para os quais eu irei fazer isso são gets e seters:

```
$obj->get  +   $restanteDoNomeDoMetodo + ()
```

ao tentar realizar esta junção, esta ocorrendo erro, o interpretador de código está identificando o get como variável, sendo que o mesmo é parte do nome de um método que existe em uma classe alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Tentei algumas variações para concatenar como termos entre '' e {} todas elas resultam em erro

```
$stmt->bindValue(":{$this->columns[$i]}",
                 $this->entity->{'get'.ucfirst($this->columns[$i]).'()'});
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar neste questão desde já obrigado.

```
Erro: Notice: Undefined property: Cliente::$getNome() in
      C:\Users\Vinicius\Desktop\pdo\ServiceDb.php on line 67
1
```

Comment: Primeira coisa leia: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.magic.php e http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get e http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set o jeito que você está fazendo esta errado... !!! leia os 3 links!

Comment: Tem uma possivel solução: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005890/6510304 verifique se ajuda.

Comment: Virgilio eu olhei os links, mas não entendi o que está errado.
Obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver Everson

$stmt->bindValue(":{$this->columns[$i]}",$this->entity->{'get'.ucfirst($this->columns[$i])}());

Comment: Mas para 'concatenar' nesse caso não seria o sinal de **+** e sim **.** (ponto).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode montar o nome do método utilizando o conceito de [funções váriaveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.variable-functions.php)

```php
<?php
//classe para de teste com get e set
class teste{
  private $nome = "";
  public function getNome(){
   return $this->nome;
    }
  public function setNome($nome){
   $this->nome = $nome ;
   }
}

//criando um objeto para utilizar
$teste = new teste();

//chamando o primeiro método através de um funcção variável
$metodo = "setNome";

//fazendo o teste para verificar se realmente existe...
if(is_callable(array($teste, $metodo))){
  $teste->$metodo("NOME DO FULANO");
}else{
  // trate aqui o erro caso nao exista...
}

// trocando o método
$metodo = "getNome";

if(is_callable(array($teste, $metodo))){
  echo $teste->$metodo();
}else{
  // trate aqui o erro caso nao exista...
}
```

o resultado será

```
NOME DO FULANO
```